# ¿Porqué se rechaza el reporte a una pregunta basada en opiniones?

Tags: discusión

Me causó mucha curiosidad ver que reporté una pregunta ([Varias duda sobre los open-soruce](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/288582/varias-duda-sobre-los-open-source))  porque sus respuestas podrían estar basadas en opiniones y dicho reporte fue rechazado.

Sin embargo, cuando voy a ver de nuevo la pregunta aparece en espera por la misma causa que yo reporté.

Quizas no entienda muy bien aún el flujo de los reportes a preguntas... por eso pregunto.

¿Cual pudo ser la razón de que mi reporte haya sido rechazado?.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rechace tu reporte porque como bien dice el rechazo, no usaste un reporte comun para rechazarlo.

Usaste un reporte a un moderador, cuando alcanzaba con reportarla como basada en opiniones. No es que rechace el reporte (de hecho, fui quien termino cerrandola), si no que rechace el tipo de reporte que hiciste.

Si hubieras hecho un reporte comun, hubiera entrado en la cola de publicaciones de baja calidad y eventualmente hubiera terminado cerrada.

Tene en cuenta que los reportes a moderadores (sobre usando el item otros) son para casos excepcionales. Una pregunta basada en opiniones debe entrar por los canales habituales.

Si tenes mas dudas, podemos hablarlo en el chat o donde gustes.

Y otra cosa, tener un reporte rechazado no implica nada. Todos (yo inclusive) tenemos reportes rechazados por distintos motivos (inclusive el sistema mismo rechaza reportes automaticamente).

Comment: Valida la aclaración. Se que no implica nada, solo quería entender el "por qué".

Comment: Gracias a dios que preguntaste rapido.. mañana ya ni me iba a acordar que hice LOL

Comment: :P ............